# How to configure Azure Front Door Standard (not Classic) to failover timely and failback?

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

**Setup**

I have an Origin Group with 2 web sites: one is the "main" site and one is a "static" site. Front Door caching is disabled. There are no other devices / proxies / caches between Front Door and the web sites.

The origin group is configured as:

- Health probe: 10 seconds
- Session affinity: not enabled
- All other settings as default

The origins are configured as follows:

- main: Priority = 1, Weight = 1000
- static: Priority = 2, Weight = 1000

NOTE: All testing using an incognito session and using ctrl-shift-r to force a reload in both Edge and Chrome. I have used this site as the refrence for what *should* happen: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/routing-methods#priority

When I load the web site, it correctly goes to "main".

**Failover Behavour**

When I stop the "main" App Service, I would expect it to "think" for 10 seconds and then load the static site. But it does not. Instead, it does this:

- 0 to 30 seconds: "The web site is unavailable" (white background black text)
- 30 seconds to 120 seconds (in another test, it was much longer - it does not seem to be consistent): "Error 403 - This web app is stopped." (or just 403 if I'm oit using friendly errors. Develper Mode shows that I am receiving a 403 which is the main point, not a 200.)
- 120 seconds onwards: The static page shows

**Failback Behaviour**

When I restart the "main" App Service, I would expect it to "think" for 10 seconds and then load the main site. But it does not. Instead, it does this:

- 0 to at least 10 minutes onwards: The static page shows

**Conclusions**

1. Azure Door does not failover as per the probe settings. (So, either the probe does not work, or it does but is ignored by Front Door.)
2. Failback is not supported in Front Door.

How do I:

1. Get Front Door failover to work faster than 2 minutes after a failure?
2. Get Front Door to fail-back after the main site is up and running? (Purging the AFD cache does ot fix it. The only way I have found is to delete [not just disable] the "static" origin.)

Comment: Azure Front Door routes the traffic globally via AnyCast. Anycast will route traffic to the nearest edge location if a request comes in. If any preferred edge location is unhealthy, all traffic will route to the next closest edge location by default.

In which regions did both main and static applications get hosted?

Comment: Everything is in Europe North. Is there documentation that says that all Origins must be in different regions? Certainly AFD let's be add Origins from the same region.

Comment: No, in my view, traffic routing will happen using all 4 methods [latency, priority, weight, and session affinity]. That's the reason I am cross-checking the region where the apps were hosted. Currently, it is set to "Priority."

My suggestion is, "If regions are deploying origins in two or more locations across the globe, you can improve the responsiveness of your applications by routing traffic to the destination that is "closest" to your end users."

Comment: OK, so the "If regions are deploying origins in two or more locations across the globe" doesn't apply in my case which means we're back to square 1. Hopefully someone will have seen this before.

Comment: As an aside - following the failover, I left it as "main": Priority = 1, Weight = 1000;  "static": Priority = 2, Weight = 1000 for the whole weekend. All traffic is still going to "static" but "main" is up and running.

Comment: Mark, here is the best performance practice we can do on Front Door, which I suggested in the solution and replicated the same. Please apply session affinity and disable the unused endpoints at the front door. As mentioned in the above comment, if endpoints are enabled at the front door, traffic will go to the respective priority application. That doesn't mean the main application will be down. It will be raised, but not through the front door. Please review my points 1–3 on solutions. I hope it's helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249594/discussion-between-mark-and-swarna-anipindi).

Answer (score -1):

If regions are deploying origins in two or more locations across the globe, you can improve the responsiveness of your applications by routing traffic to the destination that is "closest" to your end users. Based on my experience, here are my recommendations.

1. Enable session affinity
2. Deploy applications from various origins to improve portal performance with Load Balancers [Front Door, Traffic Manager, Load Balancer, Application Gateway].
3. Disable unused endpoints.

Replicating the same scenario with two apps and the above rules, both applications are loading fine without any issues.

[image]

[image]

[image]

step2:
**I disabled EndPoint 1 and tested the FD portal.**
[image]

Static application is running fine
[image]

**The same step is repeated by the disabled App Services application.**

[image]

WebApp Running fine.

[image]

Comment: This is not an answer because as per the comments, they are NOT deployed to different regions, hence the downvote. Moreover, generic instructions on how to set up load balancing in Front Door to not relate to the OP.

Comment: Accept my apologies for any confusion; I replicated the above solution in the same region, not a different region, Mark!

Following the implementation of a few checks, everything is working as expected. I disabled the front door and tested both endpoints separately.